# Powershell getcontent from arranged report

Tags: powershell, csv, getcontent

just new to powershell.
I need an listed report taken from such below txt report.
this is only some lines of example. I have more than 10000 lines such kind of this.

> 

```
 PIPELINE REF LINENUMBER_A
 BATCH REF XXXA
 PIPING SPEC 01B

                                            N.S.         LENGTH                                     QTY     QTY
          BOLT DESCRIPTION                  (INS)        (MM)         ITEM CODE                     FAB     EREC
          ----------------                  ----         ------       ---------                     ---     ----

  70 STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts          1/2          70           0597461                     0       4
     B18.2.1/B18.2.2 A320-L7M/A194-7M (S3)
     SPUN GLV TO F2329 INCH SIZE

1          31 Mar 2021                                                                                         Page     1

 PIPELINE REF LINENUMBER_B
 BATCH REF XXXB
 PIPING SPEC 01C

                                            N.S.         LENGTH                                     QTY     QTY
          BOLT DESCRIPTION                  (INS)        (MM)         ITEM CODE                     FAB     EREC
          ----------------                  ----         ------       ---------                     ---     ----

  90 STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts          5/8          90           7452665                     0       16
     B18.2.1/B18.2.2 A320-B8M CL2
     (S1/S3)/A194-8MA INCH SIZE
  210 STUD BOLTS & 3 HH Nuts                1.1/8        210          9989993                     0       16
     B18.2.1/B18.2.2 A320-B8M CL2
     (S1/S3)/A194-8MA INCH SIZE-With a 3rd
     nut for tensioning
```

The result I expected as comma separated is enough as below:

LINENUMBER_A,01B,STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts,1/2,70,0597461,0,4
LINENUMBER_B,01C,STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts,5/8,90,7452665,0,16
LINENUMBER_B,01C,STUD BOLTS & 3 HH Nuts,1.1/8,210,9989993,0,16

I've tried

```
$p = @("PIPELINE","STUD BOLT")
Get-Content '.\bolt-out.bom' | Select-String -Pattern $p -SimpleMatch | Set-Content test0.txt
```

but the result is not as expected. anyone can help realy appreciate.

the result is below. I only may need something like concatenate of first array finding + second finding instead of new line number.

```
PIPELINE REF LINENUMBER_A
90 STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts          5/8          90           7452665                     0       16
```

Comment: "the result is not as expected" - but what _is_ the result like? Close to what you need? Not at all?

Comment: please wrap your data in code format markers so that it shows without distortion.

Comment: The code you have tried is nowhere close to what would be needed to create the output you desire. You'd need to take the whole report, split it into PIPELINE REF sections, then parse for the table within it and create records including both PIPELINE REF info as well as itemized record info.

Comment: Just curious.. Why do you repeat the last value ('QTY EREC') in the desired output where this is not in the text file?

Comment: I just added the output sample above, 
Sorry for the inconvenient  just put them in the code format.
Sorry for the repeated QTY EREC i expected it has to be TOTAL QTY = EREC + FAB but as long as I get as per the input file it does not matter for me will exercise in the excel with CSV file .
Any better suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest parsing this into a nice CSV file with column headers:

```
# read the file as single multilined string and split on `PIPELINE REF`
$result = (Get-Content -Path '.\bolt-out.bom' -Raw) -split 'PIPELINE REF' | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    # split the part in separate lines and trim to get rid of all leading and trailing spaces
    $lines = ($_ -split '\r?\n').Trim()
    $lines[0] = 'PIPELINE REF ' + $lines[0] # re-add 'PIPELINE REF'
    # create an empty item
    $item = '' | Select-Object LineRef,PipingSpec,Description,NS,Length,ItemCode,QTY_Fab,QTY_Erec,Total_QTY
    # parse line by line
    switch -Regex ($lines) {
        '^PIPELINE REF (\w+)' { $item.LineRef = $matches[1] }
        '^PIPING SPEC (\w+)'  { $item.PipingSpec = $matches[1] }
        '^(\d+.*)\s{2,}([^\s]+)\s{2,}([^\s]+)\s{2,}([^\s]+)\s{2,}([^\s]+)\s{2,}([^\s]+)' {
            $item.Description = $matches[1]
            $item.NS          = $matches[2]
            $item.Length      = $matches[3]
            $item.ItemCode    = $matches[4]
            $item.QTY_Fab     = [int]$matches[5]
            $item.QTY_Erec    = [int]$matches[6]
            $item.Total_QTY   = [int]$matches[5] + [int]$matches[6]
        }
    }
    # output the item
    $item
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to comma separated CSV file (WITH headers)
$result | Export-Csv -Path '.\boltsandnuts.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen should look like:

```
LineRef     : LINENUMBER_A
PipingSpec  : 01B
Description : 70 STUD BOLTS & 2 HEAVY Hex Nuts        
NS          : 1/2
Length      : 70
ItemCode    : 0597461
QTY_Fab     : 0
QTY_Erec    : 4
Total_QTY   : 4
```

Regex details of the long regex line:

```
^               Assert position at the beginning of the string
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d           Match a single digit 0..9
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   .            Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)              
\s              Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   {2,}         Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [^\s]        Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)              
\s              Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   {2,}         Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [^\s]        Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)              
\s              Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   {2,}         Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4
   [^\s]        Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)              
\s              Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   {2,}         Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 5
   [^\s]        Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\s          # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   {2,}        # Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 6
   [^\s]       # Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: unbelieveable. It almost there, sorry for late response as project is hectic nowadays.

the pipeline ref is empty in screen also in csv. anything we miss? Can I attach sampel input file in this forum? I have 21891 row input file that we can test together.

Comment: Made a small change for the `PIPELINE REF`. Should be populated now